# Django datetime parsing fails with legacy database

Tags: django, datetime

I am trying to use the existing database from [digikam](http://www.digikam.org) and create a DJango app for it. But on opening one model in the admin, I get problems because of a `DateTimeField`.

I used the import from legacy db function [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/), and it worked fine (I can use two tables already). The generated model for the `images` table is:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    album = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.IntegerField()
    modificationdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column=u'modificationDate', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    filesize = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'fileSize', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    uniquehash = models.TextField(db_column=u'uniqueHash', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Images'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name
```

On calling the relevant admin pages for it, I get the a "ValueError" and the trace shows that it is trying to convert the string `'2012-09-30T11:35:35'` to a datetime.

Two problems

1. If I set `modificationdate = models.TextField(...)` the error remains, and it still tries to convert the above string to a datetime. Why?
2. If I add a fitting format to the tuple of DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS (Namely, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') in settings.py, the error remains. How do I have Django accept my additional format?

Using Django 1.3.1 and sqlite3. Removing the line `modificationdate = ...` gets rid of the problem.

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL?

Comment: No, sqlite3, as I mentioned in the last paragraph.